# Escaping character "\" in regular expression (find text between curly brackets)

Tags: php, regex, escaping

my current task is to transform string, and replace text between "{ }" by any mentioned character inside,

for example, string: a{b|c}d{e|f}h, and possible results:

```
'abdeh'
'abdfh'
'acdeh'
'acdfh'
```

At this moment, I have got a function

```
function producePatStr($str) {

    return preg_replace_callback('/{+(.*?)}/', function($matches) {

        $separated_chars = explode("|", $matches[1]);

        return $separated_chars[array_rand($separated_chars)]; 


    }, $str);
```

which works fine, but can you please help me to edit my regex, to "ignore" opening bracket if it has escaping char "\" before it, to be like that:

```
a{b|c}d\{e|f}h
```

and result should be like:
 abd{e|f}h or acd{e|f}h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should work for you

```
function producePatStr($str) {
    return str_replace('\{', '{', preg_replace_callback('/[^\\\]{([^}]*)}/', function($matches) {
        $separated_chars = explode("|", $matches[1]);
        return $separated_chars[array_rand($separated_chars)]; 
    }, $str)
    );
}

$text = 'a{b|c}d\{e|f}h';
$output = producePatStr($text);
var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!\\){[^}]*}
```

You can use `lookbehind` for the same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/44

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, but how to use this regex in my function??? Simple replacing causes an error

Warning: preg_replace_callback(): No ending matching delimiter ')' found in ....
and my code is :
preg_replace_callback("(?<!\\){[^}]*}", function($matches) {

Comment: @user2858470 `$re = "/(?<!\\\\){([^}]*)}/" `